# Calculate the penny double after each day of working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a table, which the pay of day 2 is double from day 1, day 3 is double from day 2 and keep doubling. There are 5 days to display and then calculate the total pay of 5 days.

But the result was just 0.02 from day 1 to day 5. What did I miss?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int entries;
    double pay = 0.010000;
    double sum = 0;
    int day;


    cout << "Enter number of days";
    cin >> entries; //Number of day

    cout << "Day   Pay\n";
    cout << "=========\n";


    for (day = 1; day <= entries; day++)
    {
       cout << day << "\t\t" << (pay * 2);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Where do you update `pay`?.  2) Even if you updated `pay`, don't be surprised if your calculations start to get imprecise due to floating point issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update the pay variable in each iteration:

```
for (day = 1; day <= entries; day++)
{
   cout << day << "\t\t" << pay<<endl;
   sum += pay;
   pay *= 2;
}

cout << "Total is\t\t" << sum <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the doubling from day to day. Your current code is only printing out twice the starting value each day. Try something like:

```
for (day = 1; day <= entries; day++)
{
    cout << day << "\t\t" << pay;
    sum += pay;
    pay *= 2;
}
```